# "If I want to start doing something"

Tags: translation, english-to-japanese

How to ask for advice if I want to start doing something, for example:

> If I want to start watching Tv-shows, from which should I start?
> If I want to start doing exercises, how should I start?

Is there specific grammar for it? Can I say something like this:

> もし私はドラマを見たい初める、からどんな始まりますか？

Answer (score 1):

For recommendations about shows, I would probably go with

> 新しいドラマを見てみたいです。何かいいドラマを知っていますか？

adding the tentative てみる, because if you start doing something you are not quite sure how it will eventually go or if you'll stick to it.

Answer (score 0):

A literal translation of your question would be:

> ドラマを[見]{み}[始]{はじ}めたいです。どれから[始]{はじ}めるべきですか。

However, a more natural way to ask the question would be 'Do you have any recommendations?', which is:

> ドラマを見始めたいです。お[勧]{すす}めはありますか。

Comment: 「見始めたい」って言うかなぁ、こういう時？

Comment: @l'électeur I'm definitely open to suggestions on how to improve. Does 見たい seem better to you?

Answer (score 0):

運動を始めるとしたら、何から始めるといいですか？

ドラマを見始めるとしたら、何から始めるといいですか？